# Send a MIME Email with PUTTY

Tags: email, putty, smtp, mime-types

Im currently wondering how to send a mime mail with putty, important is, for now i only want to "declare" the mail as a mime mail if thats possible. I dont want to send an actual picture,video etc. with it. I know how to send a normal SMTP mail via putty but have been struggling with this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/38919/send-an-email-with-an-attached-file-using-telnet-or-netcat

Comment: Can you describe what you mean "with PuTTY"? Are you directly connecting to an SMTP server via port 25, or are you trying to do this from a Linux command-line?

Comment: Yes im connected to an SMTP Server on port 25

Answer (score 0):

First, add the `MIME-Version:` header. That's the official declaration per [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045.html) – although in reality, practically all mail apps will always treat messages as MIME *anyway*, even if they lack this declaration, but the standard nevertheless says "MUST".

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Second, set the correct `Content-Type:` header. For example, if you're just sending a plain-text email, you should specify `text/plain` as the "MIME type":

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

That's pretty much it – now it's *officially* a MIME message containing a single text part. *(Though you probably should add `Content-Transfer-Encoding` as well, if you're using non-ASCII characters.)*

---

Later, when you want to make a multipart message – that needs to be specified in the outermost Content-Type, which uses one of the special "multipart" MIME-types, e.g. `multipart/alternative` for dual plain+HTML messages or `multipart/mixed` for attachments. The real content type is then specified individually for each part. For example, an HTML message with an attached photo would have this structure:

```
multipart/mixed
├─ multipart/alternative
│  ├─ text/html
│  └─ text/plain
└─ image/jpeg (Content-Disposition: attachment)
```